# Rails 4 actionmailer not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, gmail, actionmailer

I've tried everything I can think of to get emails to send with Rails 4.1.6 (local development) but nothing is working.  Using Postmark I have the following in my development.rb and application.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :postmark
config.action_mailer.postmark_settings = { :api_key => API_KEY }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

and for GMAIL I tried:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'gmail.com',
  user_name:            'my_email',
  password:             'my_password',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

My Mailer class looks like so:

```
class BusinessMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "my_email@email.com"

  def claim_business business

    mail(
      :subject => 'hello',
      :to      => 'myemail@email.com',
      :from    => 'myemail@email.com',
      :html_body => '<strong>Hello John Doe<strong>',
      :track_opens => 'true'
    )

  end
end
```

And lastly I'm sending the email via: `BusinessMailer.claim_business @business`

When I trigger the `claim_business` method I see `BusinessMailer#claim_business: processed outbound mail in 14.1ms` in my console with no error messages.  Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here?

Comment: Add `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` and see what happen.

Comment: @blelump I have that and don't get any additional output to the console, just the standard `processed outbound mail`

Comment: OK, what about: `BusinessMailer.claim_business(@business).deliver` ?

Comment: @blelump I should have posted this question 3 hrs ago!  It worked, if you want to add your comment as an answer I'll give you credit.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DanRamos Was calling `.deliver` the solution? I am having the same problem, but I am definitely calling `.deliver`... actually, its `.deliver_now` now.

Comment: @Jeff Now, .deliver_now is not working well, rails show this error: undefined method `deliver_now'

Answer (score 18):

You're missing `deliver` method to eventually send the email. Try:

```
BusinessMailer.claim_business(@business).deliver
```

Comment: Thank you. There seems to be a change. I had my deliver method within the ActionMailer class. It was sending ok - then I upgraded to 4.2.3 and it failed silently. Putting into the calling class resolved that..